# Why is my output buffer flagged as 'disabled' by PHP?

Tags: php

My previous question ([ob_get_status() has undocumented bits set in 'flags' entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69843159)) revealed that there are some undocumented flags that may be passed into output buffer callback functions (i.e. the function specified when setting your output buffer, using `ob_start()`).

One of these flags (undocumented, but revealed by [the PHP source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/90b7bde61507cee1c6b37f153909d72f5b203b8c/main/output.c#L1008)) is `PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_DISABLED` and this is what I am receiving when I call `ob_get_status(true)` in my application.

My question is, what are the situations that can cause an output buffer to be marked as disabled?

*(Note that I am asking in the general case, rather than specifically asking about my code, as I feel that too much context would be required to give a specific answer.  If I understand the possible reasons, I hope I can deduce which of them might apply in my situation.)*

Comment: `ob_start()` excepts a `phase` [parameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php#refsect1-function.ob-start-parameters) that accepts the flags, and although I don't have time to test it right now, I'd be curious if you can pass those undocumented ones into it and get a stack trace? Its possible that only the documented ones are supported, too.

Comment: Ugh, sorry, "accepts", not "excepts"

Comment: Not sure how that will help figure out what's disabling the handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've cracked it!

It looks like there is a bug in PHP >= 5.4 that affects the way `false` is handled when returned from an output buffer callback function after a 'clean' operation.

The [documentation](https://www.php.net/ob_start) states:

> If callback returns false original input is sent to the browser.

This statement implies that the following two callbacks are always identical:

```
function OBCallback($Output) {
    return $Output;
}
```

```
function OBCallback($Output) {
    return false;
}
```

On PHP 5.3 and below, that is true - they do behave in an identical manner.  However, on PHP 5.4 and above, there is a difference when the callback is being called in the context of a 'clean' operation.

In this situation, returning `false` from the function is treated as an error, and this results in the output buffer being disabled.  This is why my code has the `PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_DISABLED` flag set in the handler's status entry; my code includes an `ob_clean()` at one point and my handler is returning false in all instances.

Paradoxically, returning the supplied buffer in response to a 'clean' operation (which contains the contents of the buffer prior to the clean) does *not* cause an error, nor does it cause the returned buffer to be output.

This is the exact opposite of what you might expect - surely, returning a non-empty buffer in response to a 'clean' operation should result in an error, whilst returning false (indicating 'continue with default action') should result in the buffer being cleaned automatically.

In addition, no PHP error, warning or notice is raised when this happens, so you will not be notified that your handler was disabled!

I have created a fiddle to demonstrate the two scenarios, to show how it differs between PHP versions: https://3v4l.org/66cai

## tl;dr

Make sure you always return a string from your callback function, rather than `false`, to avoid weird bugs (despite what the documentation says).